# How to disable button in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton

I have an image button and I want to be disabled when the program starts and upon certain condition, it needs to be enabled.

Here is my code,

```java
public Screen( ) {    //constructor
    ImageButton hints;
    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle hintsstyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    hintsstyle.up = skin.getDrawable("newrightbut");
    hintsstyle.down = skin.getDrawable("newrightbut");
    hintsstyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    hints = new ImageButton(hintsstyle);
    hints.setPosition(650, 35);
    hints.setHeight(70);
    hints.setWidth(70);
    stage.addActor(hints);
    hints.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
}

public void update() {
    hints.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
}
```

But, the button is not getting disabled when the program starts and I even tested with button.setDisabled(true) method. It also doesn't work. Any idea why? Any help would be great!! Thanks

Comment: share your variables declaration code.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is 5 months old now but I try to answer regardless.

ImageButton `hints` is declared within your constructor (So its scope is limited to the constructor).

The only way that you don't get a compilation error calling it from a method outside the constructor is if you have also declared it somewhere else within your class.

Conclusion: you must have declared it somewhere else in your application and any default, it is enabled.